# How can the shape of this variable be defined in typescript callback functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typescript

I am trying to convert an existing project which uses mongoose on nodejs to Typescript. However, I'm running into problems with defining the shape of this in some of the callback functions.
For example, my user object is defined (heavily curtailed to focus on the issue) as follows:

```
export class UserAPI{
    userSchema: mongoose.Schema
    constructor(){
       this.userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String,
                                       email: {type:String, lowercase: true}
                                       });
       this.userSchema.virtual('password').set(function(password: string){
           this._password = password;
       }).get(function(){
        return this._password;
        });
   }
}
```

The last line above (return this._password) causes typescript error. As I understand, the scope of the get and set callback functions is set by mongoose. Obviously, typescript doesn't know the shape of the this object in the callback functions and results in compiler error. Can someone help me understand how to get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously, typescript doesn't know the shape of the this object in the callback functions and results in compiler error.

It shouldn't be a compile error as `this` is assumed to be of type `any` unless you are using a lambda (`=>`) where is not the case in your code sample.

Your best bet to define the shape of this is to do something like `var foo:SomeType = this` and then use `foo` instead of `this`. Reason : Its an open issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/229).